# Scrape # of product reviews from amazon search

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to pull the amount of reviews of a product from the search results using regex. https://goo.gl/hKdGyt

To pull the price I have:

```
IWebElement firstResult = innerDriver.FindElementById(key);
string priceRegex = "\\$[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+";
string text = firstResult.Text;
Regex reg = new Regex(priceRegex);
price = reg.Match(text).ToString();
```

and it works so I tried to use:

```
string rankRegex = "\\>[0-9]</a";
string text = firstResult.Text;
Regex reg = new Regex(priceRegex);
price = reg.Match(text).ToString();
```

to pull the number of reviews but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: You should be careful, some sites have copyright from doing such things to their site.  Ie: if they see their content within your product, they can sue you.

Comment: You should consider using an HTML parser since you are scraping some data from HTML.